# Find the number of the indexpath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a hard time finding the number of rows clicked. What I found was

`(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

But I got a crazy number from that. I have an `UITableView` that shows an array with 4 items.

I also tried this:

```
    NSIndexPath *leo = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSInteger *leo2 = leo.row;
```

But `leo2` is always 0. What can I do?

Comment: NSInteger leo2 = indexPath.row;

Comment: NSinteger leo2 = indexPath.row.    Here leo2 is just a prinimitive integer not an Object. so * is not required.   Also If you want to know selected row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  method, you can directly get from indexPath.

Answer (score 4):

You have the two parts, you just need to put them together. Is this what you're looking for?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger leo2 = indexPath.row;
    id someObject = myArray[leo2];
}
```

As @nkongara points out, you had added an asterisk next to the name of the pointer implying that it was an Objective C object, when infact it is a primitive type. In this case either `long` or `int` depending on the system. For more information, see how `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are defined below.

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: Exactly man!!!!!! Looking all the web and stack overflow for this code and didn`t find!! THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as written should have given you a compiler warning.

A good rule of thumb: Find an fix every single compiler warning, no exceptions. They always indicate that's there is something wrong. Sometimes that something causes wrong results rather than crashes, but there is always a reason for compiler warnings.

One of the worst thing about warnings is that they are only displayed when you edit a source file. If you ignore them, the compiler treats the file as compiled successfully, and so you don't see the warning again unless you edit the file, or if you run a "clean" on your project. This means that if you don't fix a warning, it becomes invisible. Bad. Very bad.

Sometimes the fix is a type cast so the compiler knows the type of an object. Other times, like above, the answer is to get rid of a spurious asterisk.

Another example of code that should be changed to get rid of a warning:

We've all written the if statement

```
if (a == b)
```

(which means "if a equals b")

as

```
if (a = b)
```

instead, by accident. This second statement is technically legal, but almost always wrong. What it means is: Copy the right side of the = statement into the left side (set a to the value of b.) Then evaluate the result of the right side as the result of the if statement. So the if statement will be true if b is not equal to zero.

The LLVM compiler flags `if (a = b)` with a warning because this is such a common mistake. If you really, really want to do that, you can add an extra set of parenthesis:

```
if ((a = 0))
```

That tells the compiler that you really mean to do this. (I say anyone doing that should be shot, but that's a different issue...)

This is an example of modifying your code to make your intentions clear, both to the compiler, and to other people reading your code.